# Why is the id value wrong for the first and last element?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
_/_-- Select a Sub-server (optional) --_|_509_,Subserver 509_|_510_,Subserver 510_|_511_Subserver 511
```

And I am trying to get the following output from it:

```
const arr = [
    { id: "", text: "-- Select a Sub-server (optional) --"},
    { id: "509", text: "Subserver 509"},
    { id: "510", text: "Subserver 510"},
    { id: "511", text: "Subserver 511"},
]
```

This is the code I have built but I am missing something because the output is not as expected:

```
const values = "_/_-- Select a Sub-server (optional) --_|_509_,Subserver 509_|_510_,Subserver 510_|_511_Subserver 511";
const parts = values.split("_|_").filter(part => part.trim() !== "");
const arr = parts.map(part => {
    const [id, text] = part.split("_,");
    return { id: id || "", text: text || "" };
});
```

this is the result I got from my code:

```
console.log(arr);
[
  { id: '_/_-- Select a Sub-server (optional) --', text: '' },
  { id: '509', text: 'Subserver 509' },
  { id: '510', text: 'Subserver 510' },
  { id: '511_Subserver 511', text: '' }
]
```

Why are the first and last `id`s wrong and are missing the `text` value? Can I get some help identifying where is my issue?

Note: I am open to suggestions and improvements not tied to my code.

Comment: The last element is missing the comma. `_511_Subserver 511` should be `_511_,Subserver 511` to fit the pattern of the others. And in the first element, it's not a `|`, it's a `/`.

Comment: The first and the last part cannot be split by `_,` since there is no such string in either of them.

Comment: I think a regular expression might be a better solution. The ID is between the first two `_` characters, and the comma after the second `_` is optional.

Comment: This should have been your string

```none
_|__,-- Select a Sub-server (optional) --_|_509_,Subserver 509_|_510_,Subserver 510_|_511_,Subserver 511
```

Comment: @Swanand The input is a given.

Comment: By the way, you can also solve the problem with a regex template: `for ([_, id, text] of values.matchAll(/_(?:\|_|\/)(.*?)_,?(.+?)(?=_\|_|_\/|$)/g)) arr.push({ id, text })`. It's much shorter, though much more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `_,` separators in the first and last items, so you can't use that as the delimiter between the ID and the value.

Also, you have `_/_` before the first element, that won't be removed by any of your code. You could use another regexp to treat that as a delimiter in the first split.

Since the comma is optional, you could use a regular expression as the delimiter: `/_,?/` matches `_` optionally followed by `,`.

```js
const values = "_/_-- Select a Sub-server (optional) --_|_509_,Subserver 509_|_510_,Subserver 510_|_511_Subserver 511";
const parts = values.split(/_\|_|_\//).filter(part => part.trim() !== "");
const arr = parts.map(part => {
    const [id, text] = part.split(/_,?/);
    return { id: id || "", text: text || "" };
});
console.log(arr);
```